# Difference in handling of flexbox sizes in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

In Chrome and Firefox, flexboxes stretch to accomodate text inside them, but I cannot get Safari to mirror this behavior.

When making the window narrower, the flexboxes become narrower, and so the text gets closer to overfilling the flexbox. The desired behaviour, as occurs on Chrome and Firefox, is to make the flexboxes wrap if the text inside them would not fit otherwise, but in Safari the flexboxes keep on shrinking, with text leaking out of the flexboxes. How can I prevent the boxes shrinking beyond the text fitting inside them in Safari?

CSS:

```
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.a > div {
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 30%;
          flex-basis: 30%;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
          flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/h6aydfxr/

Resize your browser to resize the boxes.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041

Comment: @silviagreen Is there a workaround for this bug that I can use?